# Using UIPopover for a comment button

Tags: iphone, ios, uipopovercontroller

I have to create a `UITableView` of a social site

Now I got stuck on `uitableview` cell, which contains a comment button.

On click on that comment button, I want to create a Popover (in which a user can type and post).

NB: this is an iPhone app not iPad

Is it possibe? If so, please help me. And also please tell me if there are any good tutorial/sample codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. Yet, since you're on the iPhone, you need a 3-party popover class (most probably WEPopover (https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover)

Then, you can setup your popover and display it from your button.

As a simple iPad example, here is a class I created to make it simple to create a UIPopover :

```
+(UIPopoverController*)displayPopoverForRowIndex:(NSInteger)index inView:(UIView*)view fromRect:(CGRect)rect withTitle:(NSString*)title permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)direction
{
    UIViewController *contentVC = [[NDSearchDetailsController alloc] initWithIndex:index];
    UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:contentVC];

    tableVC.navigationController = navVC;

    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navVC];
    tableVC.popoverController = popover;

    popover.delegate = tableVC;

    if (view) [popover presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:view permittedArrowDirections:direction animated:YES];

    return popover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the native `UIPopover` on the iPhone, but there are some third party implementations that you could adjust to suit your needs.

- [TSPopover](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tspopover) is similar to native
- [WEPopover](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/wepopover) is for use with `UITableView`, which might be better for you
- [DDPopoverBackgroundView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ddpopoverbackgroundview) might be close to what you need for posting comments, but the review are bad

Look at [Cocoa Controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com) for more. I don't think you will have to start from scratch on this.

Answer (score 0):

[Popover controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

You can create a view with background that looks like popover and simulate popover behaviour on showing and hiding by changing views alpha.